# jQuery .animate opacity callback function

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm new to jQuery and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am trying to write a simple `.animate` function that uses a callback to run two different animations one after the other.

This is the code I currently have:

```
  $(".spring_link").click(function(){
    $("#fall_content").animate({opacity:'hide'}, 9000, function() { 
      $("#spring_content").animate({opacity:'show', top:'0px'}, 'fast');
    });
  });
```

I was under the assumption that this would cause `#fall_content` to be hidden and then once this is completed the animation applied to `#spring_content` would be run. However, both animations are taking place at the same time.

Comment: It _should_ work as you describe.  Please show the relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct: [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fBqPt/).

The callback will be invoked once for every object that is matched by the selector. Could it be that there is another element of the ID `fall_content`, that is already hidden? Because if it is, that would immediately invoke the `spring_content` animation, without waiting the 9 seconds.

In the quoted code, this cannot happen, because the selector `$('#fall_content')` can never yield more than one element. (Even if there *were* more than one element of the same ID, which is not valid HTML, jQuery would only yield the first of those elements).

From the code in your comments, however, it is shown that you use another selector, one that may yield several elements. If *any one of those elements* is already hidden, then, that element will call its callback immediately.

To work around this, you could add `not(':hidden')` after your selector; filtering out any already-hidden items from the set, which means that all remaining items will invoke the fade-in after 9 seconds.

Now, besides the fact that you may be doing several invokes at once, you're introducing another possible issue - if all elements in the selector happen to be hidden. Asking an already hidden element to invoke a callback once it is hidden, is another thing entirely from asking *no elements* to invoke a callback once they're hidden:

```
// this will invoke the callback immediately
$('#already-hidden-element').animate({ opacity: 0 }, function() { ... });

// this will never invoke the callback
$('#id-that-does-not-exist').animate({ opacity: 0 }, function() { ... });
```

So if this might ever be a concern for your (and perhaps even if you reckon it won't, because requirements may change later on, and in that case this issue will be tricky to track down), this is one of the cases where you might want to retort to a timeout instead:

```
var delay = 9000;
$('#bunch, #of, #IDs').animate({ opacity: 0 }, delay);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#spring_content').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast');
}, delay);
```

Now your timeout is guarranteed to occur only once, and always after 9 seconds from the fade out begins. Note that we're talking about a scenario where all your elements might be hidden from the beginning. In that scenario, it is likely that you *don't* want to wait 9 seconds before showing the spring content, but rather fading it in immediately, as in the original `animate` behavior. In that case, you'd have to set the delay conditionally:

```
var elements = $('#bunch, #of, #IDs').not(':hidden');
var delay = elements.length == 0 ? 0 : 9000;

elements.animate({ opacity: 0 }, delay);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#spring_content').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast');
}, delay);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! To be honest, I am extremely new to Jquery and I am sure that something else I have done is messing this up, but I don't really know where to start looking. What do you mean by "another element of the ID fall_content"? Do you mean is there something else causing #fall_content to be hidden...like a different class or id?

Comment: If it helps, here is the full block of code that I was referring to. Chances are there is something else in my jquery that is causing the issue ><

`$(".spring_link").click(function(){

$("#fall_content, #store_content, #seen_in_content, #about_content,
#ad_fall_content, #ad_spring_content, #ed_spring_content, #ed_fall_content").animate({opacity:'hide'}, 9000, function() {        $("#spring_content").animate({opacity:'show', top:'0px'}, 'fast');
$(".spring_link").addClass("active");
$(".fall_link").removeClass("active");
});
});`

Comment: That does help. You start by specifying a whole lot of IDs of elements to hide. Your callback will be called once *for every matching element* as their fade is completed. If *any one of them* is hidden, there will be no fade for that element, and the callback will be invoked immediately.

Comment: If you change your fade out to `$('your ids...').not(':hidden').animate(...)` you will filter out any hidden elements so that no element in your set will cause an immediate callback.

Comment: Ah! Okay, that makes alot of sense. I'm definitely gonna have to go back and rethink how I wrote this all out, but that definitely helps clarify alot for me!

Comment: Oh wow, I just saw that last post you made! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: My proposed solution comes with a set of issues of its own (issues that may never be of a concern for you, but still). See my updated answer for a more thorough approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
var wait = setInterval(function() {
if( !$("#element1, #element2").is(":animated") ) {
    clearInterval(wait);
    // This piece of code will be executed
    // after element1 and element2 is complete.
}
}, 200);
```

you can use set interval to wait until the other action is completed.